# Java unexpected type Error Required Variable Found Value

Tags: java

```
public boolean replaceEventAt(String eventStr, int position){
  boolean answer = false;

  if((position > 0) && (position <= events.size())){
     events.get(position - 1) = eventStr;
     answer = true;
  }

  return answer;
}
```

Error on fifth line where Java complains that position is a value not a variable please help

Comment: The left hand side of an assignment (`=`) must be a variable.  Perhaps you mean `events.set(position - 1, eventStr);`?

Comment: Hi, a suggestion to improve this question that will be helpful any time you ask for help about programming: Always copy the entire, exact error message. It has a lot of information that, even if it doesn't all make sense to you, the people answering your question will probably get a lot out of.

Comment: yes that worked thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

An assignment operates between what is known as an `lvalue` and an `rvalue`.

`lvalue` stands for left-hand-side-value.

`rvalue` stands for right-hand-side-value.

The rvalue can be many things, like a variable, a constant, a function call expression, etc, but the left side must be assignable, so it cannot be a constant or a function call.

In your case, your rvalue is a function invocation; that won't work.  The compiler error message is saying exactly that.

If we knew what you are trying to do we could perhaps explain more, but it is unclear from the code that you posted that it is that you want to accomplish. Perhaps `events` is some collection, and you want to set the element at position `position - 1` to `eventStr`, in this case you would probably want `events.set( position - 1, eventStr );`

Answer (score 0):

Left hand side must be a variable (ie we should be able to assign a value to it ). But in your case it is performing a **get operation** So it is throwing an Error

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to replace using index I assume events is object of List interface.
In this case below code should work as per your requirement.

```
public boolean replaceEventAt(String eventStr, int position){
  boolean answer = false;

  if((position > 0) && (position <= events.size())){
     events.set(position - 1, eventStr);
     answer = true;
  }

  return answer;
}
```